# Pasar registros de un DataGrid a otro DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Necesito pasar registros de un DataGrid-A a otro Datagrid-B con un boton, y al pasarlos a mi DataGrid-B eliminar mis registros en mi DataGrid-A, cada DataGrid esta en un UserControl diferente y mis registros estan almacenados en una Base de Datos SQL SERVER

Lo que tengo por el momento es una clase Datos

```
public class Datos
{
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }

    public string NombreProveedor { get; set; }

    public string OC { get; set; }

    public string Facturas { get; set; }

    public string FormaPago { get; set; }

    public string FechaRecibido { get; set; }

    public string FechaPago { get; set; }

    public string MonedaMXN { get; set; }

    public string MonedaUSD { get; set; }

    public string Notas { get; set; }
}
```

En mi DataGrid-B hice lo siguiente y me marca error que dice lo siguiente: "Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'Add' toma 10 argumentos"

```
public List<Datos> lista = new List<Datos>();
 private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var dato in lista)
        {
            facturasPagadasDG.Items.Add(dato.RazonSocial, dato.NombreProveedor, dato.OC, dato.Facturas, dato.FormaPago, dato.FechaRecibido, dato.FechaPago, dato.MonedaMXN, dato.MonedaUSD, dato.Notas);
        }
    }
```

Para mi botón hice lo siguiente y me marca un error al momento de compilar: "No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'"

```
private void btnPagadas_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       FacturasPagadas pagadas = new FacturasPagadas(); 
       foreach(DataGridViewRow fila in facturasPendientesDG.Items)
        {
            Datos dt = new Datos();
            if (fila.Selected)
            {
                dt.RazonSocial = fila.Cells[index: 0].Value.ToString();
                dt.NombreProveedor = fila.Cells[index: 1].Value.ToString();
                dt.OC = fila.Cells[index: 2].Value.ToString();
                dt.Facturas = fila.Cells[index: 3].Value.ToString();
                dt.FormaPago = fila.Cells[index: 4].Value.ToString();
                dt.FechaRecibido = fila.Cells[index: 5].Value.ToString();
                dt.FechaPago = fila.Cells[index: 6].Value.ToString();
                dt.MonedaMXN = fila.Cells[index: 7].Value.ToString(); 
                dt.MonedaUSD = fila.Cells[index: 8].Value.ToString();
                dt.Notas = fila.Cells[index: 9].Value.ToString();
                pagadas.lista.Add(dt);
            }
        }
    }
```

La verdad soy nueva en esto y no se hacerlo de otra manera, sí alguien puede ayudarme con esto lo agradecería muchísimo

Answer (score 0):

Me centraré en el problema de cambiar una factura de DataGrid no importando si está en otro UserControl (ya que eso es otro tema)

Debes ocupar Binding, para esto lo más fácil es emplear una [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0) a modo de lista contenedora de objetos.

Tú tienes una ObservableCollection que tiene tus objetos data. Haces binding al `DataGrid` usando la propiedad `ItemsSource` y todo lo que ocurra en la lista ocurrira en el `DataGrid`

Ejemplo:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Datos> facturasPagadas;
    ObservableCollection<Datos> facturasPendientes;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //llenamos las listas
        facturasPagadas = GetPagadas();
        facturasPendientes = GetPendientes();

        //hacemos el binding
        facturasPagadasDG.ItemsSource =facturasPagadas;
        facturasPendientesDG.ItemsSource =facturasPendientes;
            
    }

        

    //cambiamos de una lista a otra
    private void btnPagadas_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Datos facturaSeleccionada = facturasPendientesDG.SelectedItem as Datos;

        if (facturaSeleccionada != null)
        {
            facturasPendientes.Remove(facturaSeleccionada);
            facturasPagadas.Add(facturaSeleccionada);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Datos> GetPagadas()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Datos> pagadas = new ObservableCollection<Datos>();

        //Aqui lleno la ObservableCollection a partir de la base de datos
        //foreach ( .. ){
        //  pagadas.Add(datos);
        //}
        return pagadas;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Datos> GetPendientes()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Datos> pendientes = new ObservableCollection<Datos>();

        //Aqui lleno la ObservableCollection a partir de la base de datos
        //foreach ( .. ){
        //  pagadas.Add(datos);
        //}
        return pendientes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo hice de esta manera...

Comment: En mi foreach() me aparece una excepción de tipo "System.StackOverflowException" y ya no me deja ni abrir mi UserControl. No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal

Comment: @Sandie Si bien mi oculista me indicó que tengo vista perfecta, no alcanzo a ver tu foreach